# don't persist a form

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I have this problem with my form

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form
```

I show my form in a view like that

```
  <form id="target" action="#" data-idea="{{idea}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="add comment"/>
    </form>
```

In my controller I have this

public function addCommentAction(){

```
        $ideaId= $_POST['idea'];
        $coment= new Comentario();
        $form= $this->createForm(new ComentarioFormType(), $coment);
        $request= $this->getRequest();

        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()){
                $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $coment->setIdea($ideaId);
                $em->persist($coment);
                $em->flush();
            }
...
}
```

I have the error in `($form->isValid())`, If I debug the code,  isValid function return false when ask this ... `if ($this->hasErrors())` and show the error.

If I errase the line   `if ($form->isValid())` in my controller , the funcion don´t persist the form because the field descripcion is null.

this is my form

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('descripcion', 'textarea');

}

public  function getDefaultOptions( array $options){
    return array('data_class'=> 'ComentBundle\Entity\Coment');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'coment';
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: it's looking good, can you post all your form building code ?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Ahmad , sure I include in the ask

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused, but you have use $this->creatForm in controller and the name of your build form function is buildForm, it's different methods or not ?

Comment: yes @Mohammad Ahmad is the same that say the doc in symfony http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#building-the-form

Comment: did you try to disable CSRF protection and see what happen ?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Ahmad, yes I try to disable CSRF proteccion but don´t persist the form, because other error say that the descripcion field is null, is like $form->bindRequest($request) don´t work in this case. I have other form in my aplication and work fine, in this case I don´t no why the error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    public function addCommentAction(Request $request){
    $ideaId= $_POST['idea'];
    $coment= new Comentario();
    $form= $this->createForm(new ComentarioFormType(), $coment);


    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()){
            $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $coment->setIdea($ideaId);
            $em->persist($coment);
            $em->flush();
        }
   ...
   }
```

note the $request is from Action declare statement

I hope this will help